# angular issue on lazy route

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I am new to angular & googled for hours to find solutions on lazy route. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7jmk87

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'customers', loadChildren: './pages/customers/customers.module#CustomersModule' }
];
```

**customer-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { 
      path: '', 
      component: CustomersComponent, 
    },
    { path: 'detail', component: CustomerDetailComponent },
];
```

what I want is to redirect to `/customers/detail` from `/customers`, but it return an error like `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'detail'`. 
I follow some examples but it still not solved yet. 
I hope someone can give a hand to me. Thanks.

Comment: You can add /customers/ into the routeLink to work around. `<a routerLink='/customers/detail'>Detail</a>`

Comment: Do you want to go to customer detail component when clicked on customers link?

Comment: Notice that lazy routing syntax has changed in Angular 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of these options:

1)  full url to the page

```
routerLink="/customers/detail"
```

2) relative url with `./`

```
routerLink="./detail"
```

3) relative url without slash at the beginning

```
routerLink="detail"
```

In two latest options the router will look in the children of the current activated route.

See also [RouterLink documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Lazy route, then you need to define the `customer-routing.moudule` as below:-

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { 
      path: '', 
      component: CustomersComponent, 
    },
    children :[{ path: 'detail', component: CustomerDetailComponent }]    
];
```

And your router link will be `customers/detail` in your HTML part.

Hope this will help u.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `routerLink` to navigate as below:

```
<a [routerLink]="[ '../detail' ]">Redirect To Detail-1</a>
```

and

```
<a [routerLink]="[ 'detail' ]">Redirect To Detail-2</a>
```

Both of them are correct.

or

In the constructor of customer component inject the following service:

`Router`, `ActivatedRoute`

```
constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
```

Then if you want to redirect to detail component with `(click)` event , use the following:

```
<a (click)="redirectToDetail()"> Redirect To Detail </a>
redirectToDetail() {
  this.router.navigate(['../detail'], { relativeTo: this.route })
}
```